# Node.js + Express.js User Permission Security Model

Tags: security, node.js, express

We have an application that has two types of users. Depending on how the user logs in, we want them to have access to different parts of the application.

How do we implement a security model for preventing users from seeing things they do not have access to?

Do we make security part of each routes implementation? The problem being that we will have some duplicate logic across requests. We could move this into helper functions, but we'd still need to remember to call it.

Do we make security part of a global app.all() route handler? The problem being that we have to inspect each route and do different logic based on a multitude of rules. At least all the code is in one place,  but then... all the code is in one place.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Having it per-route usually works for me. This is what I typically do:

```
function requireRole (role) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.session.user && req.session.user.role === role) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.send(403);
        }
    }
}

app.get("/foo", foo.index);
app.get("/foo/:id", requireRole("user"), foo.show);
app.post("/foo", requireRole("admin"), foo.create);

// All bars are protected
app.all("/foo/bar", requireRole("admin"));

// All paths starting with "/foo/bar/" are protected
app.all("/foo/bar/*", requireRole("user"));
```

Comment: But what if just 2 roles can access to route?

Comment: You could make `requireRole` take an array instead? And check with `indexOf`.

Comment: Could you add example? Is this last route protect all routes that start with /foo/bar ?

Comment: What if the permissions are changed on the database? How would one make sure that session is consistent with database?

Comment: @nomadoda it seems like a bit of a different problem to me, but you would have to refresh the session somehow. It depends on what session backing store you use, easiest would be to let the user login again after that type of change.

Answer (score 9):

You can use ability-js with everyauth, which is quite similar to CanCan for Rails https://github.com/scottkf/ability-js

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [this list](https://gist.github.com/facultymatt/6370903) for NodeJS ACL/Permission systems. IMHO [OptimalBits node_acl](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl) looks best.

Comment: Is there a more recent list of Node.js ACL modules? We are considering how to implement ACL in a Meteor.js app.

Answer (score 3):

There is now Node module [permission](https://www.npmjs.com/package/permission) for this. It's very easy to use, very similar to accepted answer, but still some features are added.