# NodeJS API - security issues

Tags: security, api, node.js

I am making an API in NodeJS that 'll be used by a website and iPhone native app at the same time.

There is a chance that API URL will be exposed to user when used in javascript for website. I only want authorized access to the API. Don't want anyone call API via console. like `user/delete/[user-id]`, anyone can use this URL to delete a user.

Comment: What is your question here? You should obviously not rely on nobody finding the URL, and instead implement proper authentication and authorization.

Comment: How to do proper authentication and authorization for an API ?

Comment: For authentication, you can use a login form with cookie based sessions, or HTTP Basic Authentication, or an API key, or a third party provider (OpenID, Facebook, Twitter). For authorization, you would check that the authenticated user is authorized to do the requested operation. See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9609587/295262) for a possible starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://passportjs.org/

There are plenty of authentication strategies to use. Don't reinvent the wheel here. ;)