# Should I using separated express server for different type of user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm trying to use node.js+express.js to build web server.And their are two type of users in my site: normal user and manager. Manager have the right to write data in some field of my database, but normal user can only read them.

So my question is : should I using separated instantiation of express server for manager and normal user ? So they using different port and won't disturb each other?

Comment: Perhaps you might want your users to have different roles, take a look at the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609325/node-js-express-js-user-permission-security-model

Comment: You can follow the ACL pattern to handle with different roles. I think different servers is not the best approach for it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list

Comment: You should go with the ACL and use this package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl) for your work.It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to setting up user permissions for your backend Node.js server, but setting up separate instances of the server based on the role should not be one of them. There are many packages already out in the NPM ecosystem that could assist you in solving your problem, but depending it may be something as simple as a middleware you can write yourself for Express.js to solve your issue. Example:

```
export default function permit(...allowed) {
  const isAllowed = role => allowed.indexOf(role) > -1;

  // return a middleware
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user && isAllowed(req.user.role))
      next(); // role is allowed, so continue on the next middleware
    else {
      response.status(403).json({message: "Forbidden"}); // user is forbidden
    }
  }
}

// Use as so
app.use("/api/private", permit("admin"));
app.use(["/api/foo", "/api/bar"], permit("owner", "employee"));
```

See [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).